# USB File transfer test :How to get the details of file transfer speed, duration between PC and Android device

Tags: android, usb, adb, mtp

I'm trying to write a shell script to copy the text/media file from PC to Android device and calculating USB file transfer speed, time duration etc.

I can push the file to SD card using adb push command from my PC. How to get the USB file transfer speed, time duration, File size etc.

Also does the above mentioned steps emulate the end user scenario or is there any better ways to do this.

Comment: I believe adb already logs this, probably to stderr or else stdout.  But adb is not considered an end user mechanism - for that you need to wrangle with the incompatibilities of mtp.

Comment: Is it possible to copy contents to device over MTP programatically?